# Phone number won't appear with achemso package except when fax is listed

Tags: achemso

I'm required to include a phone number with a corresponding author on the title page of a paper.  The [`achemso`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/achemso) package uses `\phone{}` to do this.  The [documentation](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/achemso/achemso.pdf) states (on pg. 5)

> The class will recognise the optional information \fax and \phone,
>   which will be printed along with the lead authors e-mail
>   address. Note that this information is only used for authors who have
>   an e-mail address supplied.

The MWE given by the documentation is the following:

```
\author{Second Bloke}
\email{second.bloke@some.place}
\phone{+xxx (0)yyy zzzzzz}
\fax{+xxx (0)yyy wwwwww}
\affiliation[University of Sometown]
{University of Somewhere, Sometown, USA}
```

My problem is this.  I include `\email{}` and `\phone{}` but only the email will be displayed.  It isn't until I include `\fax{}` that the the phone number will appear.  Unfortunately, the fax number will also appear.

**My question is**, can I simply display an email and phone number without printing the fax number?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[journal=jpcafh]{achemso}
\setkeys{acs}{email=true}

\title{MWE: A Minimum Working Example}

\author{The Mighty Jingles}
\affiliation[Curbstompers Anonymous]
{123 Road St., City, State, 45678 USA}

\author{QuickyBaby}
\email{quickfingers@email.com}
\phone{+1 (555) 867-5309}
%\fax{+1 (555) 867-5310}
\affiliation[Curbstompers Anonymous]
{123 Road St., City, State, 45678 USA}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

**Note:** Uncommenting the fax line will get the phone to appear.

I'm compiling with `latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know whether this behaviour is a feature or a bug in `achemso.cls`, but the culprit is in these lines

```
\renewcommand*\acs@number@list{%
  \begingroup
    \acs@number@list@aux@i{phone}%
    \let\@tempb\@tempa
    \acs@number@list@aux@i{fax}%
    \ifx\@tempa\@empty\else
      \ifx\@tempb\@empty\else
        \protected@edef\@tempa{%
          \@tempb.\space\@tempa
        }%
      \fi
    \fi
    \ifx\@tempa\@empty\else
      \par
      \@tempa
    \fi
  \endgroup
}
```

Commenting out the first `\ifx` (and its associated `\fi`), gives the desired result:

```
\documentclass[journal=jpcafh]{achemso}
\setkeys{acs}{email=true}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\acs@number@list{%
  \begingroup
    \acs@number@list@aux@i{phone}%
    \let\@tempb\@tempa
    \acs@number@list@aux@i{fax}%
    %\ifx\@tempa\@empty\else
      \ifx\@tempb\@empty\else
        \protected@edef\@tempa{%
          \@tempb.\space\@tempa
        }%
      \fi
    %\fi
    \ifx\@tempa\@empty\else
      \par
      \@tempa
    \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\title{MWE: A Minimum Working Example}
\author{The Mighty Jingles}
\affiliation[Curbstompers Anonymous]
{123 Road St., City, State, 45678 USA}

\author{QuickyBaby}
\email{quickfingers@email.com}
\phone{+1 (555) 867-5309}
%\fax{+1 (555) 867-5310}
\affiliation[Curbstompers Anonymous]
{123 Road St., City, State, 45678 USA}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just to note, there is an offending period following the phone number.  I'm OKAY with that but someone else who comes along may not be.  Change `\@tempb.\space\@tempa` to `\@tempb\space\@tempa`.